# SoftException in Application.cpp:630: Could not execute script

Tags: wordpress, server

I’ll try to keep this short :)

I have internal server error on my site that comes and goes and happens like twice a week for the past 4 months. This week it happens everyday like if I’m browsing 10 pages at least one will be 500 internal server error. I had many plugins and thought that they are causing it. I deactivated plugins and still have the error, I’m using Avada theme and switch to native theme and still have the error (when I test it by opening many pages). I’m using incognito window + using www.brokenlinkcheck.com and www.drlinkcheck.com.

**Error:**

> Wed Feb 05 14:36:50.903810 2020] [:error] [pid 404293:tid
>   139773324543744] [client 38.128.66.10:0] SoftException in
>   Application.cpp:630: Could not execute script
>   “/home1/xxxxxxx/public_html/index.php”
>
> [Wed Feb 05 14:36:50.013640 2020] [:error] [pid 404293:tid
>   139773692856064] [client 5.244.163.91:0] SoftException in
>   Application.cpp:630: Could not execute script
>   “/home1/xxxxxxx/public_html/index.php”, referer:
>   https://www.google.com/
>
> [Wed Feb 05 14:36:49.740221 2020] [:error] [pid 404293:tid
>   139773681346304] [client 197.253.196.171:0] SoftException in
>   Application.cpp:630: Could not execute script
>   “/home1/hatitnet/public_html/index.php”, referer:
>   https://www.xxxxxxx.net/5280/
>
> [Wed Feb 05 14:36:48.736710 2020] [:error] [pid 412638:tid
>   139774268344064] [client 37.43.228.175:57520] SoftException in
>   Application.cpp:630: Could not execute script
>   “/home1/xxxxxxx/public_html/index.php”, referer:
>   https://www.xxxxxxx.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=10231&action=edit

Actions taken to solve the issue:

1- deactivated all plugins

2- generated new htaccess file

3- change themes

4- re-installed WordPress fresh copy

And nothing has worked.